# Power BI subscription .PNG not showing up to date data

Tags: powerbi

I love the subscription feature for Power BI reports and the fact that you get a nice .png delivered to your inbox every day. However, why does it not show the latest date in the dataset?! i.e., where is my April data in the image when this report was refreshed overnight (4/13/2020)??

[image: .png snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you subscribed yourself to have Power BI email you a screenshot of your report. Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-report-subscribe?#reports):

> Email subscriptions are sent with the report's default filter and
> slicer states. Any changes to the defaults that you make after
> subscribing don't show up in the email.

So I would assume that you had January through March selected as default filters (the filters set in Power BI Desktop
when the publisher published the report) and that means that April will never show. To confirm this click the reset filter button in the toolbar at the top of the report and see what it shows. Then talk to the report publisher and have them change the date filter to be an advanced filter of “on or after January 1, 2020”